# I'm Getting An Uninitialized Constant Error From A Recently Installed Gem. How do you fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I recently installed the Citier Gem. Its Gem a solution for simple Multiple Class Inheritance in Rails. After setting up models per the instructions and running Rake, I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Books::Writable
 */citier/core.ext.rb:33:in 'create_citier_view'
```

Its been my experience that this error message usually means the Gem is not installed properly, but I've checked my Gemfile and did a Bundler Show command and everything seems to be in order.  Apparently, the core.ext file referenced in the error is supposed to be extending ActiveRecord to create views that are utilized for Multiple Class Inheritance.

I checked all the usual places for the problem but can't seem to figure this out.  In suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this one for a couple of days now.

Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply type require 'rails_sql_views' in config/application.rb

U may need install gem rails_sql_views

Comment: Me two, I hope this will be fixed but event on rails 3.2.12 this bug appears.